# Check if user has alread visited site in browser session

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

So I have this splash screen animation that plays when you visit my website. However, I only want the animation to play the first time you visit it (in the session of course). I tried to make an if else where I check for a cookie called "Session", and if it exists, delete the div containing the animation. If there is no such cookie, create it.

Code:

```
function session() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
        $('.splash').remove(this);
    } else {
        document.cookie = "visited";
    }
}
```

I have never used cookies before so I think I might have made some errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion of your code that deals with cookies should work.

Your problem exists on this line:

```
$('.splash').remove(this);
```

Remove `this`, as it's not necessary.

That line should look like:

```
$('.splash').remove();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, you might look into the jquery cookie plugin. It makes working with cookies a breeze. You can find it here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Still not working. I'm wondering if it's because local html files don't make cookies? I'm using chrome

Comment: Pop open the developer tools of whichever browser you're using. There will be a tab labelled console. Open it. Errors, if there are any, will be displayed there.

Comment: I'll try temporarily uploading it to GDrive to see if it works on non local. Edit: That doesn't work either

Comment: Then a couple things could be happening. First, and most likely, is that when this code runs, that splash element doesn't exist yet. To solve that, make sure whichever code you're running is executed AFTER that element is drawn.You can do that by putting the script tags at the end of your html file (in the body tags), or by waiting for the page to load completely before running the script. Google will help you with that. The other possibility is that the script isn't ever running.

Comment: See my answer on using cookie functions. Chrome doesn't allow cookie access unless you are running local files from a web server.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a security restriction that doesn't allow you to access cookies unless the page is running from a web server. Firefox will work without a web server with cookies. For quick testing of local files I suggest using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

I use the below cookie functions to set cookies easily. The original code comes from w3cschools site with some modifications for IE8 cookie problems.

```
setCookie = function (c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var expires = exdate.toUTCString();
    var isIE8 = (document.documentMode !== undefined);
    if (exdays == 0) {
        expires = (isIE8 == true) ? "" : "0";
    }
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+expires);
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

getCookie = function(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

deleteCookie = function(name) {
  document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

To check a cookie you could do:

```
if (getCookie('visited')) {
    $('.splash').remove();
    deleteCookie('visited');
} else {
    setCookie('visited','true',999); //999 days expiration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem(‘visited’) !== true){
//code that executed if it is user’s first time
sessionStorage.setItem(‘visited’,true);
}else{
//code that executes if it user has already visited
}
```